# performblockandwait inside dispatch_async deadlock

Tags: ios, core-data, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using background operations heavily and I was just curious if this would ever cause a deadlock. I have a Core Data Managed Object Context set to use a private queue that is referenced (possibly simultaneously) from a few different threads using performblockandwait. Under certain conditions a background task may be kicked off via the completion of another background task.

Something like the following is a possibility since my background tasks are started when certain conditions are met, which could occur from user input on the main thread or a background task.

```
- (void)task1
{
     __weak MyClass *weakself = self;

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0),^{
         ....
         ....
         [context performBlockAndWait:^{
              BOOL condition = [weakself performDbCleanup];

              if (condition)
              {
                  [weakself task2];
              }
         }];
     });
}

- (void)task2
{
     __weak MyClass *weakself = self;

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0),^{
         ....
         ....
         [context performBlockAndWait:^{
              [weakself performDbCleanup2];
         }];
     });
}
```

Its hard to explain exactly why I need to do things this way, but I do need performBlockAndWait in both instances because this is a highly simplified version of what is happening. Long processing happens before and after the performBlockAndWait calls that I don't want blocking access to the DB Context, and also should not be blocking the main thread.

Comment: Why can't you call `-performBlock:` and get rid of the `dispatch_async`?

Comment: My database gets accessed frequently. I figured I would put code unrelated to accessing the database in its own block that runs using dispatch_async to make sure i'm not scheduling too much work on the DB queue. Am I not understanding how this all works correctly?

Comment: If you have long running background operations I recommend creating a child context and using `performBlock` on that, and then saving your changes and pushing them to the parent context.